# I'm doing an ajax call to Lists.asmx and I'm not getting anything back

Tags: web-services, jquery, sharepoint, wss-3.0

I have a sharepoint list and I'm using Lists.asmx to bring the info using ajax, but there is nothing coming back from the server.... what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
var Currentlocurl;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".vincLista").bind("click", function(){
        L_Menu_BaseUrl = "empaquetamiento"
        if (window.location.port != null || window.location.port != '') {
            Currentlocurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + L_Menu_BaseUrl;
           }
        else {
            Currentlocurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + L_Menu_BaseUrl;
          }

         var listurl = Currentlocurl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
         var listname = "Empaquetamiento";
         var query = "<Where>" + 
            "<And>" +
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Plan' />" + 
                    "<Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).data("plan") + "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" + 
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Operacion' />" + 
                    "<Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).data("operacion") + "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" + 
            "</And>" +
            "</Where>";

         var soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> \
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
            <listName>" + listname + "</listName><query><Query>" + query + "</Query></query> \
            <viewFields><ViewFields>\
                <FieldRef Name='id' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Nombre' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Descripcion' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Codigo SAP' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Proforma' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Imagen grande' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Imagen pequeña' />\
            </ViewFields></viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

      $.ajax({
           url: listurl,
           beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");
                   },
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "xml",
          data: soap,
          complete: function (xData, status) {
               $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {
                    var infoDiv = $('<div/>', {class: "pieza", text: $(this).attr("ows_Nombre") + $(this).attr("ows_Descripcion")});
                    $("#info").append(infoDiv);
                  });
               },
          contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        });
    });
});
```

and this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7",lang=''><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8",lang=''><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9",lang=''><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Empaquetamiento</title />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />

    <!-- Libraries-->
    <!-- Javascript extra-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/empaquetamiento/JS/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/empaquetamiento/JS/html5shiv-printshiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <!-- Support for IE6-8 of HTML5 elements-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/modernizr.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Css Styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/empaquetamiento.css"/>

</head>
<body>
    <button class="vincLista" data-plan="Plan1" data-operacion="inicio" >Traer info</button>
    <button class="vincLista" data-plan="Plan1" data-operacion="diseño" >Traer info</button>
    <button class="vincLista" data-plan="Plan2" data-operacion="inicio" >Traer info</button>
    <button class="vincLista" data-plan="Plan2" data-operacion="diseño" >Traer info</button>
    <div id="info" ></div>

    <button class="vincPieza" data-id="1" >Traer info</button>
    <div id="pieza" ></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/empaquetamiento.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The ajax method is being called but I never get an answer from the server, not even an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was, first of all I used acuted vowels on my list columns like "operación" and "descripción" and this words where getting me some trouble, and also I had the menu base url wrong.

Here is the corrected code, after some refactoring:

```
var Currentlocurl;

$(document).ready(function() {

    L_Menu_BaseUrl = "/empaquetamiento"
    if (window.location.port != null || window.location.port != '') {
        Currentlocurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port + L_Menu_BaseUrl;
    }
    else {
        Currentlocurl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + L_Menu_BaseUrl;
    }

    var listurl = Currentlocurl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
    var listname = "Empaquetamiento";

    $(".vincLista").bind("click", function(){
        var query = "<Where>" + 
            "<And>" +
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Plan' />" + 
                    "<Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).data("plan") + "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" +
                "<Eq>" + 
                    "<FieldRef Name='Operacion' />" + 
                    "<Value Type='Choice'>" + $(this).data("operacion") + "</Value>" + 
                "</Eq>" +
            "</And>" + 
            "</Where>";

         var viewFields = "<ViewFields>\
                <FieldRef Name='Title' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Nombre' />\
                <FieldRef Name='Imagen' />\
            </ViewFields>";

        var soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> \
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
            <listName>" + listname + "</listName><query><Query>" + query + "</Query></query> \
            <viewFields>" + viewFields + "</viewFields> \
            </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: listurl,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/GetListItems");
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soap,
            complete: function (xData, status) {
                $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
                    var infoDiv = $('<div/>', {class: "pieza", text: $(this).attr("ows_Nombre") + " - " + $(this).attr("ows_Imagen")});
                    $("#info").find("#pieza").delete;
                    $("#info").append(infoDiv);
                });
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            },
            contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug your server call using FireBug or Chrome's built-in developer tools?  You can use these tools to see the server call and server response.

Comment: Hi, yes thanks I already found out a number of problems I had, first of all L_Menu_BaseUrl = "empaquetamiento" should be L_Menu_BaseUrl = "/empaquetamiento" for it to work ok.